# Build options issue when publishing docker image

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, docker

Visual studio runs docker with a lot of command line arguments when building/running. So hitting run in debug and release mode starts up the container with no issues.

How do I make the docker file have all the mounts and environment variables so I dont have to provide any of those when publishing the container to a container registry/repo?

My docker file looks like:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Service/Service.csproj", "Service/"]
COPY ["DataLayer/DataLayer.csproj", "DataLayer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Service/Service.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Service"
RUN dotnet build "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.dll"]
```

On pressing Run docker in visual studio, it starts up the image with the following commands:
Here you can see all the cmd options visual studio provides to run the container

```
docker build -f "C:\Users\Jacob\source\repos\Service\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t service  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=Service" "C:\Users\Jacob\source\repos\Service"
```

```
docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\Jacob\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro" -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" -e "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -P --name Service --entrypoint tail service -f /dev/null
```

When I just host my container somewhere without all these cmd line options, it does not get all the mounts and command line arguments to function. I assume that all of those have to be included in my dockerfile when publishing? So how do I go about setting all those up?

For reference, this is the information provided by docker hub on inspecting the container:

```
Environment
ASPNETCORE_URLS
https://+:443;http://+:80

ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT
443

ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
Development

ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS
true

PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER
true

DOTNET_VERSION
5.0.2

ASPNET_VERSION
5.0.2

Mounts
/REMOTE_DEBUGGER
C:\Users\Jacob\vsdbg\vs2017u5

/ROOT/.MICROSOFT/USERSECRETS
C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets

/ROOT/.ASPNET/HTTPS
C:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https

Ports
443/tcp
localhost:443

80/tcp
localhost:80
```

But when I run a the published docker image on my own:

```
Environment
PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

ASPNETCORE_URLS
http://+:80

DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER
true

DOTNET_VERSION
5.0.2

ASPNET_VERSION
5.0.2

Ports
443/tcp
localhost:443

80/tcp
localhost:80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, volumes can only be mounted when starting a container. So this can be either using docker run -v option or in a docker compose file. Volumes cannot be defined in a docker file.

Environment variables can defined in docker file using ENV instruction and/or with docker run command.

Comment: So I would have to copy those mounts in the docker file by using COPY["from", "to]?

Comment: The answer depends on the reason what your containerized app need those mounts for.

The mounts you see when running from within VS have specific purpose. VS does that to achieve seamlesss development experience for developers. It is for development environments only. You do not need remote debugger mount on another machine. Other 2 mounts are for secrets and certificate. Certificates without private key can be COPY into Dockerfile. Secrets must not be part of Dockerfile or any source file.